# Já tem/irá ter salas de Chat?

Tags: suporte, chat

Quando tento acessar

> chat.br.stackoverflow.com

Sou redirecionado para os chats do Stack Exchange.

Já existe ou vai existir chat no SOpt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tem um link [bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) no menu StackExchange que te leva para a lista de salas do site:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Tem: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha

Acho que você tem que fazer login primeiro para poder ver.

O chat usa a mesma plataforma, não está traduzido, nada. Então entrando no chat geral, é só procurar por essa sala.

Comment: Acho que a resposta do bfavaretto é um pouco melhor, fico te devendo um upvote já que estou sem por 24hrs. hehe

Comment: Sem problemas, eu também acho. Prefiro que gaste lá na outra pergunta sobre tópicos :)